# InfluxDBv2 - get a remote config working as a telegraf windows service

Tags: windows, service, telegraf, influxdb-2

I'm trying to use the remote config feature of InfluxDB and Telegraf. If I set the enviroment variable with

```
$env:INFLUX_TOKEN = "thisIsMyToken"
```

and then test things with

```
.\telegraf.exe --config "https://influxdbserver:port/myremoteconfig" --test
```

it seems to be working.
When I try to install the service with

```
.\telegraf.exe --service install --config "https://influxdbserver:port/myremoteconfig"
```

the connection does not work and according to the windows event manager it can't load the config file due to "401 Unauthorized". Which is the same error I get when not setting the token before using the --test command.
I assume the problem is with the service not seeing the enviroment variable. But how can I get the variable into the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setx`, though that'll set an env var that all users on your system can view

```
setx /M INFLUX_TOKEN "ThisisMyToken"
```

[credits to kittenless_tootler](https://www.reddit.com/r/influxdb/comments/q84u9y/comment/hgnfz5b/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)